# How to deal with multiple NServiceBus instances

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

First let me give you some context. I'm working on a project for a company A. Company A is a part of much bigger organisation Z. Both companies have their own NServiceBus solutions with SQL Server transport and persistence.
Now I need to somehow make it possible for both companies to be able to talk to each other via NSB - so how do I do that?

One solution that was proposed is a intermediate database where messages from A -> Z are stored. Basically two handlers:

- first to receive message from A's NSB and store it in db
- second to read from db and place into Z NSB

Other solution which I like more is to have a *relay handler* that receives messages from A and does Z.Bus.Send(message_from_A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a gateway to send messages over http.

What kind of interaction do you want to achieve?

Take a look at [Introduction to the Gateway](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/introduction-to-the-gateway)

And [he Gateway And Multi-Site Distribution](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/the-gateway-and-multi-site-distribution)

Comment: Thanks. Those two articles are what I was looking for. However there's one issue with gateways. It doesn't support Pub/Sub which I'm pretty sure is something that's going to be one of the requirements in my project.